# Como Instalar .ipa sem usar a Appstore

Tags: ios, appstore

Estou com uma aplicação com aprovação pendente na appstore, porém preciso disponibilizar um demonstrativo para um cliente. O que tenho é o .ipa do aplicativo.

Já usei o Diwai, porém o erro que sempre aparece é: Não foi possível fazer download do app.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Se sim como?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado experimentou o "Cydia Impactor"? Claro que vc tem que ir nas configurações do iOS para "liberar" aquele app conforme a assinatura afirmando por conta que o app e "assinatura" são "confiáveis" (se colocando como "responsável" :P) ... eu não cheguei a experimentar a solução aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/263974/3635 - mas parece promissora.

Answer (score 1):

Para instalar aplicativos fora da AppStore você precisa de uma conta Enterprise da Apple [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/).

Nesse link [Install in-house apps wirelessly](http://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7) contem todos os passos para a instalação de apps iOS fora da AppStore:

Basicamente os passos utilizados são:

- Gerar o archive do projeto
- Abra Window > Organizer do Xcode, selecione a versão do archive que será utilizado e clique em Export;
- Assinar o app com o certificado de distribuição Enterprise;
- Selecionar a opção de gerar um arquivo manifest (plist) para a instalação over-the-air;
- No final desse processo será gerado um arquivo .ipa e outro .plist. Suba esses arquivos para um servidor https (se o servidor onde for subir os arquivos não for https não será possível instalar o aplicativo no iOS).
- Adicione um link para download na página onde deseja disponibilizar o download desse aplicativo, o formato será `<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/manifest.plist”>Instalar Aplicativo</a>`. Ou execute esse link `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/manifest.plist` direto no safari do iOS

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o xcode, instalar e rodar, segue [Tutorial](https://docs.monaca.io/en/products_guide/monaca_ide/deploy/non_market_deploy/)

No tutorial mostra usando o itunes, o xcode o OTA e várias outras soluções
acredito que possa ajudar

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight é uma solução gratuita fornecida pela Apple para testar um aplicativo iOS antes de ser lançado na App Store. É uma alternativa que você pode considerar para testar seu aplicativo caso a versão AdHoc ou o app My GoodBarber não sejam opções ideais para o projeto no qual você está trabalhando. Pelo que vi até agora, o TestFlight pode ser útil para alguns revendedores.

```
>     O processo é bastante simples. 
>     1 - você faz o upload do aplicativo no iTunes Connect 
>     2 - você envia um convite para aqueles que vão testar o aplicativo 
>     3 - eles testam o aplicativo usando o aplicativo TestFlight
```

No entanto, há alguns aspectos a serem considerados.

Veja o passo a passo no link a seguir: https://pt.goodbarber.com/blog/como-testar-seu-aplicativo-com-o-testflight-a767/

É muito simples e funcional, basta subir o app e adicionar os tester, convidar e eles instalarem, irá sem encaixar perfeitamente no que vc está precisando.